# Are we allowed to "flatten" domains in calculus 3?

Tags: calculus

If we're taking the limit of some function say $f(x,y)=xy^{xy}$ as $(x,y) \to (a,b)$ are we allowed to make the substitution $u = xy$ and essentially flatten the domain from 2D to 1D?

I.e., is it valid to do something like this:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,b)}(xy)^{xy} = \lim_{u \to 0}u^u$

I'm not sure we are allowed to do this, because we've gone from infinite paths of $x,y$ to only two possible paths of $u$ (because it is now 1D)

Comment: "As $(0,b)\to(a,b)$" is weird nonsense. How does $(0,b)\to (a,b)$? And how does that affect something defined on $(x,y)$? And do you mean $(xy)^{xy}$? Because $xy^{xy}$ means $x(y^{xy})$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant (x,y) ---> (a,b). changed it

Comment: Did you mean $(xy)^{xy}$, too, or do you really mean $x(y^{xy})$, which is what your question currently asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

Long answer:
The statement $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,b)}$ implies that the limit exists and takes a unique value independent of the path chosen.

By setting $u=xy$, you are choosing a smaller family of paths. So the limit might exist in the smaller family, but not in the larger family.

Comment: Is it correct to think that the family of paths of $u=xy$ are just the level curves of the function $z=xy$ (where $z=u$)

Comment: Are you really choosing a smaller set of paths? If $f(x,y)=g(xy)$ for some $g$ then $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)=\lim_{u\to ab} g(u)$ .

Comment: This isn't correct. What happens here is you choose any curve in $x$ and $y$ *then* "project" down to $u=xy$ and do your algebra. That is, we process the curve before using it, but the major thing is that we can still run any curve through this whole process. (Note that $u$ isn't a constant here, so $u=xy$ doesn't define that $x$ and $y$ must lie on a fixed hyperbola)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. Essentially, what you are noticing is the following. We may write
$$g(u)=u^u$$
$$u(x,y)=xy$$
and then
$$f(x,y)=xy^{xy}=g(u(x,y))$$
this is the composition of continuous functions and we may write
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,b)}g(u(x,y))$$
however, along any path, the inner function has a limit of $u(0,b)$. Thus, we have:
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow u(0,b)}g(u)$$
which is what you have. That is, we are using the fact that $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is a continuous map to show that it respects all the structure necessary to make such a substitution.

Comment: Dangerous to use $u$ as a variable and a function name, well-intended though it is.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the answer is yes.

Because
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,xy\,\right|
&\le\left|\,x(y-b)\,\right|+\left|b\right|\left|\,x\vphantom{b}\,\right|\\
&\le\frac12\left(x^2+(y-b)^2\right)+\left|b\right|\left(x^2+(y-b)^2\right)^{1/2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
if $(x,y)$ is close to $(0,b)$, then $xy$ is close to $0$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{u\to0}g(u)=L\implies\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,b)}g(xy)=L\tag{2}
$$
In the question, $f(x,y)=g(xy)$ where $g(u)=u^u$. Applying $(2)$, we get
$$
\lim_{u\to0}g(0)=1\implies\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,b)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,b)}g(xy)=1\tag{3}
$$

Comment: Actually, it is $(x,y)$ close to $(0,b)$, and it can be done in general because multiplication is continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: thanks. I missed the $b$. I have updated my answer to account for it.